# In Chrome / History, how to open all tabs from a different synced computer's window?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, history, browser-tabs, google-sync

I have several computers across the house. On my main computer, I'm working on several projects at once, so I have say 10 Chrome windows open and 20 tabs per window. Now, for whatever reason sometimes I have to be in another room, but I wish to continue one of my projects. However, I can't open all 10x20 = 200 tabs because that's way too slow and unnecessary. It would be possible to just go to Chrome History, scroll to the computer I want to sync from, Open all. But, what I need is to open one window (full of tabs), not the other windows. I could click the tabs open one by one, but again, that's too slow.

I have already extensions Session Buddy and Tabs Outliner, but they don't help with this. Chrome's own History is very close, but it doesn't have Open Window buttons, only Open All.

What's the solution to Open Window from Chrome History?

Answer (score 1):

My best call to this problem would be using the extension OneTab https://www.one-tab.com/ then merge all tabs into OneTab, then using the share link and post it to yourself.
However, this is far away from working automatically.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I found a good answer (workaround solution) to my question:

Go to chrome://history/syncedTabs (same as ctrl+h and then from the top-left corner "Tabs from other devices). Then F3 to get the find popup, type there the name of the remote computer your looking for. Now you can see the page titles if you don't already remember exactly what titles you're looking for. Type in the find popup a part of the exact title you're looking for. Hit esc and your title is now selected with black borders. Hold ctrl and start opening these tabs into new tabs with enter, up arrow, enter etc.

This is a very quick way to open the ones you want. Note that if you do up arrow (as instructed) instead of down, you'll end up with the original tab order and not the reverse order.

Comment: Of course it's also possible to simply ctrl + leftclick on all the tabs you want to open in new tabs, but with keyboard (as suggested) it's much quicker/reliable, if you have a large number of tabs to open.